# Unrar creating files with backslashes in names instead of proper directory hierarchy

Tags: linux, rar

I'm working on moving the content of a website, which was provided to me in a RAR archive, to a new server.

I'm not exactly sure which flavor of Linux it is; `uname -a` tells me:

```
Linux bolt.sonic.net 2.4.37.5 #1 SMP Mon Aug 17 10:15:36 PDT 2009 i686 unknown
```

and `unrar --help` tells me:

```
UNRAR 3.00 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2002 Eugene Roshal
```

I'm not a regular user of unrar, but in my limited prior experience, the simple command `unrar x archive.rar` has always done the right thing, as far as I can remember.

But when I try to unpack the current archive, the result is a flat-structured directory containing 4500-odd files and directories whose names have backslashes in them where directory-separators should be, e.g.:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 yoyodyne user         4096 Jan 18 14:53 yoyodyne
drwxr-xr-x    2 yoyodyne user         4096 Jan 18 14:53 yoyodyne\application
drwxr-xr-x    2 yoyodyne user         4096 Jan 18 14:53 yoyodyne\application\config
-rw-r--r--    1 yoyodyne user         2765 Sep 15  2011 yoyodyne\application\config\database.php
-rw-r--r--    1 yoyodyne user         1152 Sep 15  2011 yoyodyne\application\config\doctypes.php
-rw-r--r--    1 yoyodyne user         1844 Sep 15  2011 yoyodyne\application\config\foreign_chars.php
-rw-r--r--    1 yoyodyne user          513 Sep 15  2011 yoyodyne\application\config\hooks.php
-rw-r--r--    1 yoyodyne user          123 Sep 15  2011 yoyodyne\application\config\index.html
...
```

I'm at a complete loss to understand what's causing this to happen, or how to get around it. I'm not seeing any obvious options on the `unrar` command that tell it, for instance, "Hey, I'm on a Linux system", or "Hey, ignore the fact that this archive was created on a Windows system."

(Actually, I don't know whether the archive was created on a Windows system or not. The developer who sent me the archive didn't say, and promptly went on vacation immediately afterwards -- meaning that my chances of getting an answer, or a replacement archive in a different format, are slim.)

For what it's worth, the `unrar` program seems to understand that the part of the name after the last backslash is the actual filename. The part of the output of `unrar l archive.rar` corresponding to the partial directory listing above is:

```
 Name             Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 database.php     2765     1071  38% 15-09-11 10:57   .....A   13CDB2C8 m3g 2.9
 doctypes.php     1152      381  33% 15-09-11 10:57   .....A   F25E706F m3g 2.9
 foreign_chars.php     1844      856  46% 15-09-11 10:57   .....A   12AF75FD m3g 2.9
 hooks.php         513      285  55% 15-09-11 10:57   .....A   4029E30E m3g 2.9
 index.html        123      107  86% 15-09-11 10:57   .....A   E8DFAEB4 m3g 2.9
 ...
 config              0        0   0% 18-01-13 14:53   .D....   00000000 m0  2.0
 ...
 application         0        0   0% 18-01-13 14:53   .D....   00000000 m0  2.0
 ...
```

So given this, and given that the `unrar` program is running on a Linux system, why is it creating these crazy filenames? And what can I do about it?

Comment: I think the bolt.sonic.net shell server runs Red Hat. Is there any way you can run a newer version of unRAR to see if it behaves the same way?

Comment: Maybe, but probably not today. And almost certainly not on a sonic.net server (which means that when I _do_ get a chance to run it, I'll be changing two variables). For the moment I'm trying to work around it by unarchiving on my Mac laptop (via Stuffit Expander) and then creating a tar archive to upload. Hopefully sonic.net can do the right thing with a tar archive. :-/ Thanks for the tip about them running Red Hat...

Comment: `uname -a` tell you which Linux (kernel) version it is. I assume you wanted to find out which distribution (e.g. CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, ...) it is. As far as I know there is no command to discover that, though `ls /etc` might help. (e.g. if it has a file *slackware-version* then it is slackware). 

Are for rar, my rar claims `UNRAR 4.20 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal`. Which means there is a newer version and you can test that (either on the destination, or try it first on your laptop to check if it works).

Comment: Actually, I ran `uname -a` mainly so that I could include the output in my OP, in case _any_ part of what it said might be helpful in figuring out the problem. :-) As to running a newer version of unrar on the sonic.net server, I now see that my earlier remark ("almost certainly not on a sonic.net server") was a little premature, since I could upload an executable myself, assuming I can find or build an architecturally-compatible one. Or maybe I could even build from source on the sonic.net server, if they have the necessary build tools.

Comment: @Hennes You might be interested in this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/ . I tried the `cat /etc/*-release` suggestion on the Sonic.net shell server and got `Red Hat Linux release 7.3 (Valhalla)`.

Comment: Ta. LSB_release is new to me. Until now I just did the ls /etc/*release* thing.

Comment: It may not be widely supported. It didn't work for me on that Red Hat 7.3 server...

Comment: Is it possible that somebody operated on the rar file with other tools? I've encountered /-vs-\ confusion with rars on occasion, but not quite in the way you describe. For example, when creating a rar with the rar command, and unpacking it with the Python rarfile module, by default the directory separators remain \, not /, though you can adjust them via rarfile.PATH_SEP...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution for `unrar` itself, but if you can run [`vidir`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vidir) and if you manage to unpack the archive content as a flat-structured directory, then this is what you may try to convert it to a directory tree:

```
# cd to the directory
find . | sort | vidir -
```

This will open your text editor. Use its features to replace every `\` with `/` and save the file without changing its path (it's a temporary file). `vidir` will move files and directories to their new paths, creating the desired directory tree.

Notes:

- Fancy characters in filenames are not supported, `vidir` expects textual input with standard newlines as entry separators (it won't work with `find . -print0` or `sort -z`).
- I used `sort` to ensure every line representing a directory precedes its content-to-be. It's important because `vidir` will create missing directories while moving an object to its new path. Moving the original directory later would generate a name conflict resolvable with `~` suffix, you don't want this. You want to move the directory before its content, hence `sort`.
- Set `$EDITOR` to make `vidir` use text editor of your choice (e.g. `EDITOR=vi vidir`).
- You can try the *experimental* approach from [my other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1325219/432690) to replace characters automatically, without playing in text editor by hand. In your case the command will be:

  ```
  find . | sort | EDITOR='sed -i s|\\|/|g' vidir -
  ```