# How to replace whitespace with underscore in all filenames?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

The script given below places "underscore" instead of "whitespace" in all file names that are in a certain folder. I'm having trouble making a shell script that places "underscore" instead of "whitespace" in the names of all subfolders and files contained in them and not just in a folder.

Does anyone have any tips on how can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls | while read -r FILE; do
  mv -v "$FILE" `echo $FILE | tr ' ' '_'`
done
```

Comment: Pipe the output of `find` into your `while` loop instead of `ls`. It would be safest to read the manual and use options such as `-maxdepth`. You could also look at the `-exec` option to avoid the loop altogether.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`rename` utility](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) instead, e.g.

```
rename "s/ /_/g" *
```

> Perl-powered file rename script with many helpful built-ins.

---

For recursive renaming, try:

```
rename "s/ /_/g" **/*.*
```

where `**` is a [Bash globbing option](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (enable by `shopt -s globstar`).

Alternatively use `find`, e.g.

```
find . -type f -execdir rename "s/ /_/g" {} ';'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use find to search in dirs and subdirs:

```
while IFS='' read -r -d '' fname ; do
   nname="${fname##*/}"
   mv -v -n "${fname}"  "${fname%/*}/${nname//[[:space:]]/_}"
done < <(find "$(pwd)"  -name "* *" -type f  -print0)
```

`find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0` - Prints all the found file paths in current dir and subdirs.

With the process substitution output of find command is sent to while loop where it reads variable fname.

`nname="${fname##*/}"` - Extracts file name from path

`"${fname%/*}"` - extracts the path

`"${nname//[[:space:]]/"_"}"` - replaces spaces in the filename with _

`"${fname%/*}/${nname//[[:space:]]/"_"}"` - path/new_filename

Comment: You need to remove the double-quotes around the underscore; since it's already in double-quotes, they apparently get treated as literal characters and end up in the filename. Also, I recommend adding double-quotes around `$(pwd)` in case it contains spaces (or just use `.` instead), and add `-name "* *"` to the `find` command to skip files that don't have spaces, and add either `-i` or `-n` to the `mv` command to avoid data loss if there's a filename conflict.

Comment: Good points. Double quotes inside double quotes  work in my shell but I will change that too. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently the treatment of double-quotes in that context changed sometime between bash v4.2 and bash v4.4. I was testing with bash v3; you probably have a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` (not sure on derivatives and `sh`!) you can use [variable substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) etc in variables

```
FILE="file name"
touch "$FILE"
mv -v "$FILE" "${FILE// /_/}"
```

HOWEVER THIS atleast does not deal with other space characters (tab etc)

Comment: Thank you Wilf! I still can not. Soon I will see your suggestion more carefully. The script I put above inserts "underline" between all words that have "whitespace". I would like the same thing to be done in the name of the files that are in subfolders

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
find . -depth -name "* *" -execdir bash -c 'pwd; for f in "$@"; do mv -nv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done' dummy {} +
```

Multi-line version for readability:

```
find . -depth -name "* *" -execdir \
   bash -c '
      pwd
      for f in "$@"; do
          mv -nv "$f" "${f// /_}"
      done
   ' dummy {} +
```

Explanation:

- `find . -name "* *"` finds objects that need to be renamed. Note `find` is very flexible with its tests, so if you want (e.g.) to rename directories only, start with `find . -depth -type d -name "* *"`.
- `-execdir` executes the given process (`bash`) in a directory where the object is, so any path passed by `{}` is always like `./bar`, not `./foo/bar`. This means we don't need to care about the whole path. The downside is `mv -v` won't show you the path, so I added `pwd` just for information (you can omit it if you want).
- `bash` lets us use the `"${baz// /_}"` syntax.
- `-depth` ensures the following won't happen: `find` renames a directory (if applicable) and then tries to process its content by its *old* path.
- `{} +` is able to feed `bash` with *multiple* objects (contrary to `{} \;` syntax). We iterate over them with `for f in "$@"`. The point is not to run a separate `bash` process for every object since creating a new process is costly. I think we cannot easily avoid running separate `mv`-s; still, reducing the number of `bash` invocations seems a good optimization (`pwd` is a builtin in `bash` and doesn't cost us a process). However `-execdir ... {} +` won't pass files from different directories together. By using `-exec ... {} +` instead of `-execdir ... {} +` we may further reduce the number of processes but then we need to care about the paths, not just filenames (compare [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1323056/432690), it seems to do a decent job but [`while read` slows it down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764233)). This is a matter of speed versus (relative) simplicity. My solution with `-exec` is down below.
- `dummy` just before `{}` becomes `$0` inside our `bash`. We need this dummy argument because `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...` (not `"$0" "$1" ...`). This way everything passed by `{}` is available later as `"$@"`.

---

More complex, slightly optimized version (various `${...}` tricks taken from [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1323056/432690)):

```
find . -depth -name "* *" -exec \
   bash -c '
      for f in "$@"; do
          n="${f##*/}"
          mv -nv "$f" "${f%/*}/${n// /_}"
      done
   ' dummy {} +
```

---

Another (experimental!) approach involves [`vidir`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vidir). The trick is `vidir` uses `$EDITOR` which *may not be an interactive editor*:

```
find . -name "* *" | EDITOR='sed -i s/\d32/_/g' vidir -
```

Caveats:

- This will fail for file/directory names with special characters (e.g. newlines).
- We can't use `s/ /_/g` directly, `\d32` is a workaround.
- Because of how `vidir` works, the approach would get tricky if you would like to replace a digit or a tab.
- Here `vidir` works with paths, not only filenames (base names), thus renaming files only (i.e. not directories) may be hard.

Nevertheless if you know what you're doing then this may do the job even faster. I don't recommend such (ab)use of `vidir` in general case though. I included it in my answer because I found this experimental approach interesting.