# Move only a certain sub-directory to a new folder with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, mv

I have a folder `Accounts` containing mail accounts, all of these folders have a folder `Archive.folder`. I want to move all of archive folders with a simple script to a new folder.

I tried this so far:

```sh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name archive -exec mv -t testnew/ {} +
```

But it moves all folders, not just the ones called archive.  I want to find all folders in the current folder called archive and move them to the folder testnew/. The path to the moved folder should be the same as before.

Existing situation:

```
Accounts
    - 1
          - archive
          - inbox
          - folder2
    - 2
          - archive
          - inbox
          - folder2

    - 3
          - archive
          - inbox
          - folder2
```

How it should look like:

```
testnew
    - 1
          - archive
    - 2
          - archive
    - 3
          - archive
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK to do this interactively, `vidir` may be a good way. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1225530/432690).

In your case the procedure will be like:

1. ```
   cd /path/to/Accounts
   find . -type d -name archive | vidir -
   ```
2. `vidir` will run a text editor. Use "search and replace" and replace every leading `./` with whatever path you want, so the lines match your desired directory structure. Paths may be absolute or relative, they may contain `../`. E.g. you can easily turn this

   ```
   ./1/archive
   ./2/archive
   ./3/archive
   ```

   into this

   ```
   ../testnew/1/archive
   ../testnew/2/archive
   ../testnew/3/archive
   ```
3. Save the edited file and exit the editor.

Notes:

- If your directory structure contains directories with names ending with `.` (so `./` substring appears not only at the beginning) then it will be better to replace `<TAB>./` with `<TAB>whatever/path/you/want/`, where `<TAB>` indicates the tab character. It depends on the editor if/how you can include this character in "search and replace".
- Choose your editor by specifying `EDITOR`, e.g. `find … | EDITOR=kate vidir -`.
- `vidir` is not able to move files between filesystems. If all `archive` directories belong to one filesystem and you want `testnew` to be in another filesystem, then create `testnew` in the source filesystem, use `vidir` and finally move `testnew` to the target filesystem.
- At the end of [this another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1325219/432690) there is an experimental approach that (ab)uses `EDITOR` to make `vidir` non-interactive. However **I find `vidir` useful in cases like yours mainly because it allows me to make sure the resulting paths are really what I want before any renaming/moving occurs. If I mess anything up, I can abort without saving changes.** If you want a non-interactive solution to your problem then `vidir` is not the best tool.