# Trying to unzip a file inside sub directory getting error: caution: filename not matched

Tags: linux, bash, zip, unzip

So I have a script that iterates over zip files, lists their content with unzip -l $filename, and looks for matches to pattern `(.*)report.xml`, in this case yields  `test0\report.xml`

But when it tries to unzip using `unzip -j $filename`, I get `caution: filename not matched:  test0\report.xml`

I stopped and tried manually on a file which lists:

`7285  2018-05-04 13:34   test0\report.xml`

Then doing

`unzip -j 2747693b-7027-44d3-98f4-a01f1ed139cf.zip test0\report.xml`

Gives me the error `caution: filename not matched:  test0report.xml`

I tried calling with `\\` to escape it, then same error but saying `test0\report.xml` instead.

I tried everything like \, or /, or // so I dont think this is backwards slash escaping issue.

Please help.

Comment: Side note: is `unzip -j $filename` just an example? if it's a part of your script, make it `unzip -j "$filename"`.

Comment: Ok, why? it worked for all other files I needed to extract so far from other archives (they were not in a subdir with wrong slash, howeveR)

Comment: If the variable contains spaces etc., the command will get more arguments than you expect and they won't be sane. If you're sure spaces cannot happen, you may get away with unquoted shell variable. Still, it's a good general practice to quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recreated the issue in my Kubuntu. The file name was literally `test0\report.xml` and when I did

```
unzip -j foo.zip test0\\report.xml
```

`unzip` returned `filename not matched: test0\report.xml` although the string it got should match, I think.

The tool supports some wildcards. I was able to unzip the file with this command:

```
unzip -j foo.zip 'test0?report.xml'
```

A bug? I guess you have to add some logic to your script or just to unzip by hand whenever such (hopefully rare) situation occurs again. Or take advantage of these wildcards supported by `unzip` and instead of matching `(.*)report.xml` in the script let `unzip` do the job:

```
unzip -j foo.zip '*report.xml'
```

Comment: Interesting observation! Not correct however, I just downloaded the zip file to my windows machine to test, the test0 is a directory, containing report.xml. However your work around does work! I do get the `warning: 2747693b-7027-44d3-98f4-a01f1ed139cf.zip appears to use backslashes as path separators`

Comment: Now I have another problem... My script was using unzip -j $i $filename - now I need to find a way to put a question mark instead of ```\```

Comment: I guess I will replace `$filename` with `'*.report.xml'`... Thanks!

Comment: Where do we file a bug report for unzip? although will be a few years until corporate distros get it :)

Comment: @Carmageddon Bug report? Frankly I don't know. Note: [similar situation with `unrar`](https://superuser.com/q/544786/432690).

Comment: Ok, thats not working in my script :( When I do `unzip -j $i '*report.xml'#$filename` - I get error `caution: filename not matched:  *report.xml#test0\report.xml` $i being the zip filename currently being looped

Comment: @Carmageddon I don't know what you're trying to do with this code. I was referring to "script […] looks for matches to pattern `(.*)report.xml`" and advised you to make `unzip` handle all the matching – like `unzip -j "$i" '*report.xml'`.

Comment: never mind, it worked :) I think I had to wrap $i in quotation just  like you showed here... it still complains and cautions, but it inflated the files. Thanks!